# SSO for selected Users Only

Tags: single-sign-on

In our Org we have two Applications A & B. We need to Implement SSO Authentication only for users in Application A.

When users in Application A logs In they should be redirected to SSO login page and User in Application B should be able to login via SF only.

How can I achieve this, Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is object called Profile in SFDC. Those can be aligned to users in both applications. To implement SSO for application A users, you can enable a field called "is Single Sign-On enabled" in that Profile which is aligned to the users in Application A.
Un-check the field for Application B users so, that they can access SF directly.

Prasad.